# Search Through Markers with Google Maps API Like in Google's My Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I've created a map that has the ability to toggle data (markers) and added a search box, but I want to be able to search through my markers like in Google's My Maps, but everything that I've searched for doesn't have this feature and I've clicked just about every link there is on the first two pages and [this is the closest I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136873/how-to-use-google-maps-to-search-my-own-location-data-same-functionality-as-pla), but I'm trying to find (b) and the answer to (b) in this situation is to find any entrees within a certain radius.

This is the search feature that I'm trying to add: [Example of Google's My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=zXgU8uMwOwFA.kuVqxNbjjch0) : If I search pancakes, the top results that I get are places that are on the map in which I've mentioned pancakes (instead of any place that serves pancakes).

Everything that I've done so far has been in html/javascript, so if it is possible, please try and stick to those languages.

I'm using Google's Maps API instead of My Maps because I wanted to do some extra toggling with the data that didn't seem possible with My Maps, eg make lower rated restaurants have lower opacity.

Thanks!

Comment: So you want (b) that has the search function of (a)? That may be hard to implement and may be a violation to the [Places API Policy](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies) as storing content is a restriction.

Comment: @adjuremods no, I'm pretty sure want nothing to do with (a).  I already have the markers that I want (restaurants that I've eaten at) and want to search through those where I've had pancakes easily.